# How race conditions will caused by context switching

Tags: c++, operating-system, linux-kernel

I want to know how race condition will happen during context switching, and where and how this happens.

I know about race condition can occur when accessing shared resource, I just need to understand it better. Can someone help me grasp this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a classic example:

```
int global_int = 0;

void update () {
   ++ global_int;
   /* generated assembly is something like
       register = global_int
       increment register
       global_int = register
   */
}
```

Say the first thread starts running, calls `update()`, but gets interrupted (by a signal, context switch, whatever) in-between the second and third instructions. At this stage `global_int==0` and `register==1`: it hasn't saved the result yet.

Now suppose a second thread runs `update()` and completes, so `global_int==1`. The first thread resumes and saves `register` (which is 1) to `global_int`, yielding no change.

In this situation, `global_int==1` after **two** calls to `update()` have completed. Anything which assumes that `update()` updates `global_int` will now be broken.

In general it is *very* hard to detect this problem by looking at *code*, you have to *analyse the **data*** and say to yourself "`global_int` is being accessed by different threads, I'd better guard it with a mutex". If you try to get clever and worry about *how* the threads will access it so as to avoid the expense of a lock, you will probably get it wrong except in trivial cases.

Answer (score 1):

Race conditions are a consequence of concurrent execution code which accesses a shared resource without proper mechanisms to ensure the consistency of that shared resource.

A race condition could occur during context switching if there is a bug in the implementation of the thread scheduler that causes the code used to perform the context switch to access a shared resource without providing proper consistency guarantees. There is nothing about the code that implements context-switching that makes it unable to contain race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you were on a single-processor machine with a scheduler that is basically performing time-slicing of the available processor's resources (i.e., we're on a *really simple* system).  Then suppose you have a critical section of code, but you did not guard that critical section with a mutex or other synchronization primitive.

Assume `thread A` is inside the critical section.  When the time-slice for `thread A` is up, the scheduler schedules another `thread B` and stops `thread A`.  `Thread B` then enters the critical section (since there was no guard), and modifies the values in shared memory in the critical section.  When `thread B's` time-slice is up, the OS schedules `thread A` again which continues from the point it left off inside the critical section.  The only problem now though is that the values `thread A` is working with are not what they were when it was stopped for the context-switch ... they're completely different since they were modified by `thread B`.  Thus you have a race-condition.